# New to Excel VBA , trying nested loops and getting compile error

Tags: excel, vba, compiler-errors

I'm new to Excel VBA and have double and triple checked my code and still can't seem to find the issue. 
I'm trying to iterate through a column (A) and create a unique identifier of the concatenation of value in column C and a random number between 1 and 6MIL. I am also iterating through column C.

Appreciate any help in advance!

Here is my code:

```
Sub unique_id()

    Dim c As Range

    For Each i In Range("A:A")
        For Each x In Range("C:C")
            If IsNull(i.Value) = True Then
                i.Value = Concat(x.Value, RandBetween(1, 6000000))
            End If
        End If
        Next x
    Next i


End Sub
```

Comment: You have a superfluous `End If` in your inner loop.

Comment: What specifically is the compiler complaining about?  If you're trying to use worksheet functions in VBA then you need to use `Application.FunctioName()` or `Application.Worksheetfunction.FunctionName()`   Also probably a good habit to use `Option Explicit`, which will force you to declare all of your variables.

Comment: You declare `c As Range` and don't use it. You use ranges `i` and `x` which you didn't declare. Are you aware that *For Each i In Range("A:A")* will loop through all 1,048,576 cells in column A, for each of them looping through 1,048,576 cells in column C, for a total of 1048576 * 1048576 loops? That is a number Excel can't calculate (Overflow error). If I were the Compiler I would also complain.

Comment: BTW, it's unlikely that `IsNull(i.Value)` will ever be *true*. Frankly, I don't know if Excel accepts to store a `Null` value in its cells. `IsEmpty()` might be the better choice. But `Null`, `Empty`and `Nothing` have very precise meanings. While you are still cutting your VBA teeth stick with the simple `If i.Value = "" Then`

Comment: I get a compile error on the `RANDBETWEEN` function because I use an older version of Excel.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things that need addressing in your code:

- You are doing a nested loop over all cells in 2 columns (that's over 1,000,000,000,000,000,000 calculations per loop), as you can figure, not the best idea, rather set the range at the beginning
- Dim all of your variables correctly, as pointed out in the comments
- I'm assuming by using the `IsNull()` function you are implying that there's no value in the cell? In that case it's better to use `if val = "" then`
- You need to take into account error checking, part of this being that if you are creating unique IDs you need to check whether they really are unique (already exist or not)

Try the following code out, adjust as necessary

```
Sub unique_ID()

Dim c As Range
Dim rng As Range
Dim uniqueID As String
Dim dupeFlag As Boolean    'flag to check for duplicate IDs

Set rng = Intersect(ActiveSheet.UsedRange, ActiveSheet.Columns("C"))    'goes through only the cells which have been used

For Each c In rng.Cells
    If CStr(c.Offset(, -2).value) = "" Then 'checks if col A has any value inside
        dupeFlag = True   'turns flag on for the while loop
        Do While dupeFlag
            uniqueID = c.value & Application.WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(1, 6000000)  'create the unique ID
            If findDuplicate(uniqueID, rng.Offset(, -2)) = False Then   'checks if the ID already exists
                c.Offset(, -2) = uniqueID   'if ID doesn't exist then then write it to col A
                dupeFlag = False   'flag turns off to go to next cell
            End If
        Loop
    End If
Next

End Sub

Function findDuplicate(val As String, srchRng As Range) As Boolean
'function to check if a duplicate is found in a range (the above macro calls it)

Dim cell As Range

    For Each cell In srchRng.Cells
        If cell.value = val Then
            findDuplicate = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next

    findDuplicate = False

End Function
```